# How to buffer out all changes where a sub group did not actually change?

Tags: sql, t-sql

A simple concept but well how can I code this?

I have a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPCASE (
    [Rank] [numeric](38, 0) NULL,
    [Case ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Date From] [datetime] NULL,
    [Date To] [datetime] NULL,
    [Status] [numeric](38, 0) NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)


INSERT INTO #TEMPCASE ([Rank], [Case ID], [Date From], [Date To], [Status], [Text])
VALUES 
(1, 'MI1181628', '2020-01-08 00:00:00.000', '2020-02-26 00:00:00.000', 25, 'In progress'),
(2, 'MI1181628', '2020-02-27 00:00:00.000', '2020-03-06 00:00:00.000', 25, 'In progress'),
(3, 'MI1181628', '2020-03-07 00:00:00.000', '2020-05-06 00:00:00.000', 25, 'In progress'),
(4, 'MI1181628', '2020-05-07 00:00:00.000', '2020-06-09 00:00:00.000', 30, 'Awaiting'),
(5, 'MI1181628', '2020-06-10 00:00:00.000', '2020-07-10 00:00:00.000', 25, 'In progress'),
(6, 'MI1181628', '2020-07-11 00:00:00.000', '2020-08-09 00:00:00.000', 25, 'In progress'),
(7, 'MI1181628', '2020-08-10 00:00:00.000', '2020-08-11 00:00:00.000', 40,  'Reviewed'),
(8, 'MI1181628', '2020-08-12 00:00:00.000', '2020-08-30 00:00:00.000', 43,  'Ready for invoicing'),
(9, 'MI1181628', '2020-08-31 00:00:00.000', '2020-09-05 00:00:00.000', 50, 'Closed'),
(10, 'MI1181628', '2020-09-06 00:00:00.000', '2020-10-03 00:00:00.000', 50, 'Closed'),
(11, 'MI1181628', '2020-10-04 00:00:00.000', '2020-10-09 00:00:00.000', 50, 'Closed')
```

And what I want to achieve is to buffer out all the changes where the status did not actually change. So the desired output should look like this.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqxGR.jpg)

For now, this is what I've been trying, but as you can tell, it doesn't work well. Getting bogged down now, please send your help...

```
SELECT
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Case ID] ORDER BY [Date From] ASC) AS [Rank],
       [Case ID],
       [Date From],
       [Date To],
       [Status],
       [Text]
FROM (
       SELECT   
              MIN( [Rank] ) AS [Rank],
              [Case ID],
              MIN( [Date From] ) AS [Date From],
              MAX( [Date To] ) AS [Date To],
              [Status],
              [Text]
       FROM (
              SELECT
                     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Case ID] ORDER BY [StatusChange] ASC ) AS [Group],
                     *  
              FROM (
                     SELECT 
                           CSL.*,
                           CAST(CSL.[Status] AS Varchar) + '|' + ISNULL( CAST(CSL2.[Status] AS varchar), CAST(CSL.[Status] AS varchar) ) AS [StatusChange]
                     FROM  #TEMPCASE AS CSL
                     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT [Rank], [Status] FROM  #TEMPCASE ) AS CSL2
                           ON CSL2.[Rank] = CSL.[Rank] + 1
              ) AS T1
       ) AS T2
       GROUP BY [Group], [Case ID], [Status], [Text]
) AS T3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to get the status of the "previous" row (of a case) and then check if it's the same as for the "current" (of a case) row.

```
SELECT [Rank],
       [Case ID],
       [Date From],
       [Date To],
       [Status],
       [Text]
       FROM (SELECT [Rank],
                    [Case ID],
                    [Date From],
                    [Date To],
                    [Status],
                    [Text],
                    lag([Status]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Case ID]
                                        ORDER BY [Date From]) l
                    FROM #tempcase) x
      WHERE l IS NULL
             OR l <> [Status];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c99226e94d61909ca5ff8623fd55fa7)